# ES6: Restricting the Base Class to a Singleton

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, es6-class

I have two (2) sub classes off a single super class (base class); I get two instances if I new B and C -- both include the base class by extension.

> Question: Is it possible to place a Singleton restriction on the super
>   class, and if so, how?

```
class A {
  constructor(id) {
    // => I don't want to make this call (2) times, 
    //  once for B and again for C.
    let {
      firstName: this._FirstName 
    } = CollectionName.findOne({userId: id}); 
  }
}

export class B extends A {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
  }
  get FirstName() {
    return this._FirstName;
  }
}

export class C extends A {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
  }
  get FirstName() {
    return this._FirstName;
  }
}



import { B, C } from 'imports/server/a-b-c.js'

const b = new B('123')

const c = new B('456')

const FirstNameB = b.FirstName;

const FirstNameC = c.FirstName;
```

EDIT:

I'm going to try to answer the questions here.

> @ Quasimodo's clone: What is your intention having a singleton pattern? Are you just in doubt if subclassing could generate multiple super class instances? Or do you try to prevent multiple subclass instances - super class should force that new C returns all the time the same C instance?

The base classes call out to MongoDB and retrieve LOTS of data (if there's only one class its the base class).  When I have two classes extending a base class, I don't want to call out to Mongo and store all that data multiple times.  ATM I'm using the singleton patter to keep this from happening with just stand alone classes, but I'd really like to use this pattern in cases where I have two classes that use the same base class.

Said in a different way,
The problem that I've verified is happening: when I have two classes calling out to one base class, the base class's constructor is being called twice, and Mongo is being hit twice.  ATM I don't have a singleton pattern set up for the base class when it's called by extension.

Now I need to figure out how to apply a singleton pattern on a base class extended by multiple classes.  And since the base class is actually the same instance of the subclass, I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: Although more than 1 question on SO should be posted in multiple distinct posts to fit the SO Q/A format... What is your intention having a singleton pattern? Are you just in doubt if subclassing could generate multiple super class instances? Or do you try to prevent multiple subclass instances - super class should force that `new C` returns all the time the same C instance?

Comment: An instance (this) is created with each `new`. This is the purpose of `new`, the name says it all. It doesn't matter if a class inherits another one or not.

Comment: @estus Even if it is against the semantics, JS does provide the ability to override constructors default return by simply writing `return someObject;`. However, due to the design of prototyping concept I don't believe that one could find a tricky way to prevent a subclass' constructor from beeing executed. You would need to implement the singleton pattern in the final class. The latter is definitely possible. Or the implementation could be done in the super class, as long as it is called from the sub class' constructor. [example](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern)

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I'm not talking about constructor return but about default behaviour. Question 1 probably results from OP's misconception from his previous question that super class has its own this. Of course, if super returns a singleton, there will be only 1 instance, no matter if it's instantiated directly or from subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Let's generate some test outputs to the console first. You should run it in your browser to get a full featured console access:

```js
class Base
{
    constructor(value)
    {
        this.prop = value;
    }

    funcBase() {}
}

class B extends Base
{
    constructor(value)
    {
        super(value);
    }

    funcB() {}
}

class C extends Base
{
    constructor(value)
    {
        super(value);
    }

    funcC() {}
}

let
    b = new B('instance b'),
    b2= new B('instance b'),
    c = new C('instance c')
;

// Do instances of class B and class C have the identical prototype?
console.log( 'proto(b) === proto(c)',
              Object.getPrototypeOf(b) === Object.getPrototypeOf(c)  );
              // false

// Do the prototypes of those instances b and c have the idendical prototype?
console.log( 'proto-proto(b) === proto-proto(c)',
              Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(b)) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(c)) );
              //true

// Do two instances of class B have the identical prototype?
console.log( 'proto(b) === proto(b2)',
              Object.getPrototypeOf(b) === Object.getPrototypeOf(b2) );
              // true

// Is b's prototype's prototype identical to Base.prototype?
console.log( 'proto-proto(b) === Base.prototype',
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(b)) === Base.prototype );
//true

// Let's inspect the prototypes in the console
// What is the prototype of b
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(b) );                        // an instance with constructor B() and funcB()

// What is the b's prototype's prototye?
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(b)) ); // an instance with constructor Base() and funcBase()

// Inspect constructor function B()
try      { console.dir( B ); }
catch(e) { console.log( B ); }  // [right click the "B" in the output and open in variable inspector]
```

As you can see, the `class` keyword actually compiles for you a constructor function and a prototype instance.
The instance is referenced by the constructor function in its `prototype` property. If it extends a super class, the prototype's prototype will be identical to the `prototype` property of the super class constructor (see `__proto__` property below). When you create
a new instance of the class B using the keyword `new`, a new object is created and the prototype referenced
by the constructor is assigned to the prototype of the new object. Most browsers expose the instance's prototype in the `__proto__` property. However, you should access it via the `Object.getPrototype` method.

Within the inspector you can use the `__proto__` property to traverse the tree.

Consequently the answer to your question is: You do not need a singleton design pattern, since the identical prototype
once instantiated on constructor creation time is reused everytime you utilize the keyword `new` to create a new
instance. You can see the behavior in the example when comparing `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(b)) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(c)) )`. Both prototype chains refer to the identical super class instance.

You should read further documentation about JavaScript's prototyping concept. It might appear very complicated and strange, in particular when you come from typical OOP languages, but it is based on a pretty simple design.